# "Less than or Equal To" Rational Approximations

Tags: nt.number-theory

Dirchlet's Approximation Theorem states that for $k$ real numbers $b_1, b_2, \ldots, b_n$, and $N\in \mathbb{N}$ there exists a $q\in\mathbb{N}$ such that for all $1\le i\le k$, there exists integers $p_i$ such that $|b_iq-p_i|\le \frac{1}{N^{\frac{1}{k}}}$.

Note that in some sense these approximations can be both lower or upper bounds. For a particular application I need rational approximations of this form in only one direction. In particular, I was curious if the following result holds. For positive real numbers $b_1,\ldots,b_k$ and any $\epsilon>0$, there exists a positive integer $q$ such that $0\le (qb_i-\lfloor qb_i \rfloor)\le \epsilon$ for $1\le i \le k$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is false in general, consider any irrational $b_1\in (0,1)$ and $b_2=1-b_1$. Then $qb_1-\lfloor qb_1 \rfloor+qb_2-\lfloor qb_2 \rfloor=1$ for any positive integer $q$, thus if $\epsilon<1/2$, your $q$ does not exist.

On the other hand, if $b_i$'s and 1 are rationally independent, we may say even more: for any intervals $\Delta_i\subset (0,1)$ there exist a positive integer $q$ such that fractional part of $qb_i$ lies in $\Delta_i$.

Comment: Is it not a theorem that $q$ does exist (satisfying the positive relations in the problem) if there are no rational dependencies between the b_I?  Gerhard "Not Remembering His Linear Algebra" Paseman, 2017.03.10.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman if $b_i$'s and 1 are rationally independent, we may say even more: for any intervals $\Delta_i\subset (0,1)$ there exist a positive integer $q$ such that fractional part of $qb_i$ lies in $\Delta_i$.

Comment: Indeed.  Good as your answers are, I think adding your comment to this answer would make it even better.  Future readers might then discover the relevant approximation theorems sooner.  Gerhard "Your Choice About Adding, However" Paseman, 2017.03.10.

Comment: Out of curiosity how does one prove the second part of the statement?

Comment: @mssmath Actually the vectors $\{qb_i\},q=1,2,\dots$ are uniformly distributed on the torus $(\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z})^k$. This follows from the fact that for any function $f(x_1,\dots,x_k)=\exp(2\pi i(a_1x_1+\dots+a_kx_k))$, $a_i\in \mathbb{Z}$, not all $a_i$ are zeros, we have $\sum_{i=1}^N f(qb_1,\dots,qb_k)=o(N)$.